# WP_User_Query pulling ACF to loop

Tags: custom-field, user-meta, advanced-custom-fields, users, wp-user-query

I'm using following code to display my users on template

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$paged -= 1;
$limit = 100;
$offset = $paged * $limit;

$args  = array(
    'number' => $limit,
    'offset' => $offset,
    'role'         => 'editor',
);

global $wp_query;
$wp_query = new WP_User_Query($args);

// Get the results
$authors = $wp_query->get_results();


 foreach($authors as $author) : 

     echo $author->description; 

  endforeach;

?>
```

Which works perfectly fine, however I would like to also display custom fields which I have created by using plugin Advanced Custom Fields. I have managed to do that on author.php page with this code:

```
$author_id2 = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
$author_badge = get_field('profile_picture', 'user_'. $author_id2 ); // image field, return type = "Image Object"

<img src="<?php echo $author_badge; ?>" alt="<?php echo $author_badge['alt']; ?>" class="alignright" />
```

But I'm not sure how to display the same field in my WP_User_Query.
Any tips will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know or at the moment of the last time I checked, ACF doesn't meta-data in their "best" location, as in get_term_meta, or meta data for users.

Instead of that, Elliot did a very strange thing, but focusing in what you're asking for:

```
get_field('your-field','user_' . $author->ID);
```

So the loop you will have to add something like above, check out more in his tutorial: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to/how-to-get-values-from-a-user/